# Show last Facebook Checkin

Tags: facebook, api, checkin

I have a physical locations for my business and I'd really like to display the last couple people who checked in or tagged my location in a status post.  I'm pretty new to API's and could use a little help (if it's even possible).

If this isn't possible is it at least possible to get a live view of how many checkins we've received at the location?

Forgive me if this has already been asked, I tried searching and didn't find a good answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the fql checkin table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) and search for checkins with timestamp and author-id info. I tried searching for checkins at the Golden Gate bridge -

```
SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id, timestamp from checkin where page_id = 111856692159256
```

and it seems to return public checkin results. You would probably need to sort it on your side to show the most recent checkins alone.